# Why a dimension of a vector space $V$ is equal the sum of multiplicity algebraic of eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

I read the proof in a book, but I don't understand. Can someone help me to understand, please?

> Let $T: V \longrightarrow V$ a linear operator, $V$ a vectorial space
>   with finite dimension, $\lambda_i$ different eigenvalues of $T$ with
>   $i \in \{1,..,t\}$ and the characteristic polynomial $p_T(x)$ $=$
>   $(x- \lambda_1)^{n_1}$ $(x- \lambda_2)^{n_2}$ $...$ $(x-
> \lambda_t)^{n_t}$, so $dim_{\mathbb{K}} V$ $=$ $n_1$ $+$ $n_2$ $+$
>   $...$ $+$ $n_t$ by definition of characteristic polynomial $p_T(x)$.

Comment: Note that any $n$th degree polynomial factors into $n$ linear factors

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the algebraic multiplicities is the degree of the characteristic polynomial (assuming we're working in the complex numbers) and the degree of the characteristic polynomial is the same as the dimension of the space.

This is usually proved by showing that $\det(xI-A)$ has degree $n$, where $A$ is a matrix representing $T$ and $n=\dim V$. The proof is by induction on $n$, with a Laplace development along the first row.

Comment: I understood, thanks, but is there a book that havê this proof "the degree of the characteristic polynomial is the same as the dimension of the space."?

Comment: @George Any linear algebra book should have it.

Answer (score 0):

In a finite vector space, using Jordan normal form to compute the characteristic polynomial is the right approach here. The sum of the size of the Jordan blocks equals the dimension of the vector space.

The question doesn't apply to infinite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: ok, but this proof comes before the chapter of Jordan form and this justify this using the definition of $p_T(x)$ and I don't understand why.